# Parsing content from text file using python

Tags: python, parsing

This is my code :

```
import re
a = 'CUSTOMER:SHA\n SERVICE:XX\n MOBILE:12345\n'
match= re.findall(r':[\w]+', a)
print  match
```

The output is : [':SHA', ':XX', ':12345']

I need to eliminate the colon and print the values in newline. How do i do it ?

Comment: Hey Vidhya, Have a look at this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18304835/parsing-a-text-file-into-a-list-in-python ___ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835559/parsing-values-from-a-json-file-in-python?rq=1

Comment: @RahulDambare I need to eliminate the ' : ' in the output..How does the link match my question? This is not json ...

Comment: If you understand regex, then use a group like `(\w+)`. The `[ ]` aren't necessary for your use since there is only one character the brackets

Answer (score 1):

just use this regex

```
match= re.findall(r':(\w+)', a)
```

[see this](https://regex101.com/r/wS2mO0/2)

to print on new line you can use **for** for example:

```
import re
a = 'CUSTOMER:SHA\n SERVICE:XX\n MOBILE:12345\n'
match= re.findall(r':(\w+)', a)

for i in match:
    print(i)
```

which produce this output:

> SHA
>   XX
>   12345

Comment: how extra `[..]`?? i dont use extra `[..]`

Comment: ``:([\w]+)`` and ``:(\w+)`` both do same

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate match to get each value. In each value you can then replace the colon with empty string and print it out. Here is the code you can add to what you already have to accomplish this.

```
for value in match:
   new = value.replace(":", "")
   print new
```

Comment: I think the question is asking how to parse the text without the colon, not simply print it out

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
import re
a = 'CUSTOMER:SHA\n SERVICE:XX\n MOBILE:12345\n'
for item in re.findall(r':[\w]+', a):
  print item[1:]
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
>>> re.findall(r':(\w+)',a)
['SHA', 'XX', '12345']
```